# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods not called from UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Just a caveat, this is my first ever question, be gentle with me.

I had a UITableViewController that conforms to the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol.  This all works perfectly.  I want to change that to a UIViewController to be able to add more to the view than just the tableview.  I created the tableView property and set the delegate and datasource.  Everything works fine except that the FRC delegate methods are not called and the table is not updated.  The inserts, edits, and deletes are being stored to the database, but the table is not updating when I change something in the context.

All the code is the basic template code for using a fetched results controller.  When it sets the delegate in the line:

```
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

It should be setting the delegate correctly, but it is not.  Again, the only change I make is to remove the word Table from UITableViewController.  It works with the UITableViewController but not the UIViewController.  I have researched this extensively but have not found an answer.

Thanks.

Here's some code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
.
.
.

@class NowWhatDetailViewController;
@class Event;

@interface NowWhatMasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, ChangeDateViewControllerDelgate, EditEventViewControllerDelgate, PasswordViewControllerDelegate,
    UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSMutableArray *saveButtonItems;

    IBOutlet UILabel *nextEventLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *timeToNextEventLabel;


}


@property (strong, nonatomic) NowWhatDetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChangeDateViewControllerDelgate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
.
.
.

@end


And the important sections of NowWhatMasterViewController.m


#import "NowWhatMasterViewController.h"


@interface NowWhatMasterViewController () {


}

@end

@implementation NowWhatMasterViewController {

    Event *lastEditedEvent;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self performFetch];

    [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

    self.detailViewController.viewNSDate = self.viewNSDate;
    self.detailViewController.viewDate = self.viewDate;
    self.detailViewController.viewSchedule = self.viewSchedule;
    self.detailViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.detailViewController.fetchedResultsControllerDetail = self.fetchedResultsController;

    [self.detailViewController updateDetailView];


    // show the bottom toolbar
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

    saveButtonItems = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];

    nextEventLabel.text = @"next event";
    timeToNextEventLabel.text = @"starts in ## minutes";



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Table View

/*
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [dayEvents count];
}
*/

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditEvent" sender:event];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    //return [dayEvents count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventCell"];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

    if (_isLocked) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }   
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // The table view should not be re-orderable.
    return NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [event toggleChecked];
    [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell withEvent:event];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    // this updates the detail controller when a row is selected.  Not sure we want to do that
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }
}


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }


    NSLog(@"the fetched results controller is getting the events for %@", self.viewNSDate);

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"eventNSDate" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // setup the predicate to return just the wanted date and schedule
    NSPredicate *requestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(eventDate like '%@') AND (schedule.scheduleName like '%@')", [Event returnDateString:self.viewNSDate], self.viewSchedule.scheduleName]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:requestPredicate];

    // Clear out any previous cache
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"];


    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    // manually set the delegate?

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)performFetch
{
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        //FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
        NSLog(@"database error");
        return;
    }
}



- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: You need to show us more of your code. Are you sure the fetchedResultsController is not nil when you're setting the delegate property? What about the tableview, where is it being alloc'd and where are you setting the datasource and delegate properties?

Comment: The code is posted above.

Comment: The fetchedResultsController is not nil when the delegate is set.  The table datasource and delegate are set in the storyboard.  The tableView is a property so it's not alloc'd - I tried that and it didn't matter.

Comment: I'd suggest you check if your tableview property is connected to its outlet on Interface Builder. Pause the debugger on your `viewDidLoad` method and check if the tableView property is not nil. I'd be very surprised if that is not what's causing your problem - alternatively you are going to have to investigate by simplifying the view controller code (particularly for the tableview datasource methods) and progressively adding the logic related to the fetchedResultsController.

Comment: It seems to be working now.  I had perviously set the tableView property and the delegate and datasource properties.  The difference is that I also had to connect the view to the view controller as a referencing outlet in storyboards.  That seemed to do the trick.  Thanks.